# How to display CustomComponent using the Vaadin Navigator?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using the Vaadin framework, and I'm trying to figure out how to display a CustomComponent with the Navigator.navigateTo() method.

I have a class

```
public class MyView extends CustomComponent implements View {
...
}
```

It has a Layout member.

When I call navigator.navigateTo("view", new MyView()); I don't see anything.

Any ideas on how to display a CustomComponent with the Navigator?

Thanks!

Comment: navigateTo only allows for a string (the viewname) as parameter?  what are you calling there?  CustomComponent in general works fine as a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is not the CustomComponent, but the usage of "navigateTo"

you need sth like this:

```
MyUiContent implements ViewDisplay { 
    private HorizontalLayout mainViewLayout;

    public Component init() {
        this.mainViewLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        return this.mainViewLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public void showView(View view) {
        //handle view display
        mainViewLayout.removeAllComponents();
        mainViewLayout.addComponent(view);
    }
}
```

And:

```
MyUi extends UI{
    // the rest of the initialization....
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        MyUiContent myUi = new MyUiContent();
        setContent(myUi.init());
        setNavigator(new Navigator(this, myUi);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you already know of https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html and to add/register Views to your navigator!?